# Is it possible to make multiple ANDs into only one in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to make multiple ANDs into only one? For example, something like this:

```
AND b.estado IS NULL AND c.estado IS NULL AND l.estado IS NULL
```

to be specified like this:

```
AND b.estado IS NULL, c.estado IS NULL, l.estado IS NULL
```

Comment: Is the difference between `, ` and `and ` really that great?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: no, the second syntax in your question is not supported in any database that I know.

You could, however, use `coalesce()` to shorten the expression:

```
and coalesce(b.estado, c.estado, l.estado) is null
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-`null` value from its argument list. So if it returns `null`, it means that all of its arguments are `null`.